# Extracing element rendered from ajax with scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, scrapy, splash-screen, playwright

Im trying to extract some specific price "price santander" but I'm not been able tod o using scrapy alone, I don't have any experience using playwright, splash, or selenium or some other javascript rendering service.

Here is the code I have:

```html
import scrapy
import os
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y")

class stiendaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stienda'
    start_urls = ['https://stienda.uy/tv']

    def parse(self, response):
        for products in response.xpath('//div[@data-disp="1"]'):
            name = products.css('.tit::text').get()
            price = products.css('.precioSantander::text').get()
            if name:
                yield {'name': name.strip(),
                       'price': price.strip()}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the required data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript,that's why I tried scrapy with selenium but didn'twork. So I apply original `powerful only the selenium engine with bs4` then it works like a charm.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
s=Service('./chromedriver')
driver= webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options = options)


driver.get('https://stienda.uy/tv')
time.sleep(5)
#pos= driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="wpn-popup-close"]')
#driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",pos)
#time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

data = []
for products in soup.select('#catalogoProductos .cnt'):
    price = products.select_one('span.precio > span:nth-child(2)')
    price =price.get_text(strip=True) if price else None
    name = products.select_one('.tit').get_text(strip=True)
            
    d= {
        'name': name,
        'price': price}
    data.append(d)
#print(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data).to_json('out.json')
```

**Output as json format:**

```
{
    "name": {
        "0": "Samsung Smart Tv 43\" Crystal UHD 4K 2022",
        "1": "Samsung Smart Tv 50\" Crystal UHD 4K - UN50AU7000",
        "2": "Smart TV Samsung 55\" QLED 4K 2022",
        "3": "Samsung Smart Tv 55\" UHD 4K - UN55AU7000",
        "4": "Samsung Smart Tv 65\" Crystal UHD 4K 2022",
        "5": "Smart TV Samsung 55\" Neo QLED 4K UHD 2022",
        "6": "Proyector The Freestyle",
        "7": "Samsung Smart Tv 75\" Crystal UHD 4K 2022",
        "8": "Smart TV Samsung 32\" 2021 HD - UN32T4310",
        "9": "The Frame QLED 55\" 4K Smart TV Modo Arte (2022)",
        "10": "Samsung Smart Tv 85\" Crystal UHD 4K 2022",
        "11": "Soporte Ultra Slim para TV de 13\" a 90\""
    },
    "price": {
        "0": "424",
        "1": "577",
        "2": "989",
        "3": "705",
        "4": "1.124",
        "5": "1.799",
        "6": "934",
        "7": "2.114",
        "8": "251",
        "9": "1.511",
        "10": "2.879",
        "11": "53"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I had some errors: DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:63380/devtools/browser/2bfd3864-bfb2-47f6-a943-93b0b8407cd8
[12600:18328:1114/201148.092:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [20:11:48.082] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Uno de los dispositivos conectados al sistema no funciona. (0x1F)
[12600:18328:1114/201148.092:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [20:11:48.082] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Uno de los dispositivos conectados al sistema no funciona. (0x1F)

Comment: File "C:\Users\cabre\Desktop\scraping\stienda\stienda_scraper.py", line 18, in <module>
    pos= driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="wpn-popup-close"]')
  File "C:\Users\cabre\Desktop\scraping\stienda\stienda_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 861, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "C:\Users\cabre\Desktop\scraping\stienda\stienda_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

Comment: File "C:\Users\cabre\Desktop\scraping\stienda\stienda_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class="wpn-popup-close"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=107.0.5304.107)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace: Ordinal0 [0x0039ACD3+2075859]
        Ordinal0 [0x0032EE61+1633889]
        Ordinal0 [0x0022B7BD+571325]
        Ordinal0 [0x0025AC2F+764975]
     ...

Comment: Now run the code. Pop up  isn't showing now  So I've uncommented that portion from the code

Comment: It worked with this: options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
s=Service('./chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

Comment: You may add or not you will get the output  because bs4 don't care any such pop ups just remove the pop up selection from the code